# How to Read this .JAR File

Tags: java

I have been trying to open the source code.jar and hoping to retrieve source code files in .java format with Eclipse, having no luck at all. The below screenshot is the furthest I can get.

[Sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdZQt.jpg)

The file is upload to the below link:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/v3qejrpfavy509o/AADLtEN7pvWbQLnZ8aDu7rfXa?dl=0

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is "decompiler": https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enhanced-class-decompiler

Answer (score 1):

`.jar` is the extension for a collection of compiled java classes (these classes have the `.class` extension) for the JVM to use and run, reverse engineering the source code is difficult because you need to reverse the compilation.

Some tools exist. IntelliJ has an integrated tool that helps you reverse engineer a .java file or a .jar file but once again it wont always be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

1. open the jar with a reverse tool, like jd-gui,beycompare with reverse plugin
2. read the .class file , and create refer .java. then copy content to .java
3. fix the .java compile error.

Answer (score 0):

A jar file is more or less a zip file with a specific structure. you can extract it by using the jar tool which is delivered by the jre/jdk or a zip program.

Using the jar command you can do:

```
jar -xvf <file name>
```

to extract the file.

If you only want to see the content you can use:

```
jar -tvf <file name>
```